# Fancybox 3 - Mix images and HTML

Tags: fancybox-3

In Fancybox 3, is it possible to have HTML inside an image gallery?
This HTML will have a link to an external site.
Whatever I do, it doesn't work.

```
<div id="photo-gallery" style="display: none">

   <a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" href="photo-1.jpg"></a>
   <a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" href="photo-2.jpg"></a>
   <a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" href="photo-3.jpg"></a>

   The 4th item should be just a window with a link to another site, like:

   <a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" href="www.anothersite.com">Click here</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check documentation for samples - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" data-type="iframe" href="some-page.html">4</a>
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdxPJg?editors=1000

**Edit #1**

If you want to automatically add some extra content at the end of the gallery, you can use this snippet:

```
$('[data-fancybox="photo-gallery"]').fancybox({
  onInit: function(instance) {
    instance.createGroup({
      type : 'html',
      content : '<div><h1>Hi</h1><a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" href="www.anothersite.com">Click here</a></div>'
    });
  }
})
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQmNGX?editors=1010

**Edit #2**

This is how you can mix images and inline content:

```
<a data-fancybox="photo-gallery" href="#info">4</a>

<div id="info">
  <a href="www.anothersite.com">Click here</a>
</div>
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQmNrX?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you, but isn't an iframe for displaying content from another site? All I want (if possible) is that the last item is not a picture, but a window saying "Please click here (link) to go to another site".

Comment: Of course, I didn't know my question was not precise enough. But guess what: your updated demo works like a charm! Thank you VERY much!